# $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$ iff for every $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ contains either all terms of $\{x_n\}$ or all but finitely many terms of $\{x_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$ iff for every $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ contains either all terms of $\{x_n\}$ or all but finitely many terms of $\{x_n\}$

**My idea:**

suppose ${x_n}$ converges to $0$

there there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that  for all $n>N$ we have $|x_n-0|<\epsilon$ then $|x_n|<\epsilon $

ie $x_n\in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$

is this means that $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ contains eotehr all terms of $x_n$
or all finitely many terms of $\{x_n\}$

and what about other side can you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.

Need to show :

Exists a $n_0 (\epsilon)$  such that

$|x_n| \lt \epsilon$ for $n\ge n_0$

We are given:

All or all but finitely many terms of $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon).$

Let $N_0(\epsilon) $ the maximum index  $n$ of $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  such that $ |x_n| \ge \epsilon$.

Choose $n_0 \gt N_0$:

$\rightarrow:$

$|x_n| \lt \epsilon$ for $n \ge n_0.$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is nothing to proof here because the two statements are just the definition ob a sequence converging to $0$. Your proof is showing it already. It can happen that $N(\varepsilon)$ is either equal to $1$ or larger then $1$, and that means that either all or just most elements of the sequence lie in $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$.